# How do I install a Printer using JavaScript in an HTA file?

Tags: activex, jscript, hta, activexobject

```
$('#add-printer').on('click',function(){
    console.log(newPrinter);
    var WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network");
    var PrinterPath = "\\\\Server\\Printer";
    WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection(PrinterPath);
    WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter(PrinterPath);
    // var WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network");
    // var WshNetwork =CreateObject("WScript.Network");
    // WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection(newPrinter);
    // WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter(newPrinter);
});
```

When i used **WScript.CreateObject**, I get WScript undefined so I changed it to 
**CreateObject** and I get the same message

So I tried to change the code to look like

```
 var WshNetwork = ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
```

and I get object doesn't support this action

I am not sure what else I can do to fix the problem

Comment: You want something like `var wdApp = new ActiveXObject('Word.Application');`. Also, I'm not entirely sure you can use `WScript.Network` with `CreateObject` / `new ActiveXObject`.

Comment: I stand corrected; you can use `var WshNetwork = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');`.